# .NET Core / EF core unit test

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my application, I have a repo that accesses a SQL Server database. I try to write unit tests for this method. For that, I use SQLite in memory.

My method works very well with SQL Server, but not with SQLite. Therefore unit test does not pass

```
var result = await (from command in _context.Commandes
                    where command.Numero == numero
                    select new CommandeDto
                               {
                                    Numero = command.Numero,
                                    Produits = command.Produits.Select(s => new ProduittDto()
                                               {
                                                   Id = s.s.Id,
                                                   Libelle = s.Name,
                                               }).Distinct().ToList()
                               }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Translating this query requires the SQL APPLY operation, which is not supported on SQLite.

If I remove `Distinct`, my test works

Comment: `cancellationToken.Numeroo == numero`?

Comment: Why you are using distinct at all? If I'd is unique it should be to not use distinct... You should also prefer group by over distinct

Comment: Group by not work. Il have same error

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially answered in this [GitHub issue for EFCore](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26684).  I think your only option is to perform the `.Distinct()` in memory afterwards using LINQ, not as part of your EFCore expression.